# How should I reconnect my light fixture with red, white, and blue wires?

Tags: wiring

So I have switched a lot of fixtures in my house, but this is a first.  I had drywall repairs on the ceiling, so didn’t remove the fixture the contractor did. I have no idea how it was wired in before but when I connect the fixture’s black to the red and white to white (or vice versa) the light is on regardless of the switch being on or off!

I assume they are both hot, but what do I do?[image][image]

Comment: You probably have a switch leg where 1 of the reds and whites go to the switch, you will nods to pull the switch out to know for sure

Comment: Perhaps the blue wire is switched. What happens if you connect your fixture between white and blue? That is, the fixture's black wire to the blue.

Comment: @EdBeal It sounds like you are assuming that the OP recently twisted those wires together. I assumed they were like that before. **Melissa**, which is correct?

Comment: I looked at that wire and it looked closer to green to me, with the light on all the time something has changed. Harpers answer is assuming the same as my comment Mike.

Comment: I didn’t change anything. The picture is how I found it. Again I didn’t remove it because the contractor did that

Comment: If it is blue the light would be connected to the whites and blue with a nut on the reds, I was thinking the single was green, that’s why I said the switch would need to be pulled so we know what colors were used for the switch leg. Look at the blue painters tape in the background then the single wire it looks green to me. And I just got a new phone with a much better screen otherwise I would say ?

Comment: Can you post a photo looking into the back of the box?

Comment: I added the photo looking in

Comment: @EdBeal -- lots of "blue" THHN comes out blue-green-ish, but yeah, that's a blue wire (Melissa's house is a conduit job)

Answer (score 3):

The blue wire, coupled with *the very notable* total lack of any black wire, indicates your house is NOT wired in cable.  It uses individual wires, which means it is in the conduit wiring system.  Given your ceiling being solid concrete, that is no surprise.   As such, wire colors may be whimsical as compared to diagrams you see on the Internet.  In conduit:

- neutral will be white or gray,
- ground will be green, yellow/green stripe, bare or the conduit itself
- hot will be all other colors.  Hot will never use white wire because that is not allowed in conduit.

*Generally speaking*, when you see

- a clump of hots -- note that a clump of hots *might* include *one* white wire
- a clump of *all* white wires, and
- a solitary hot

That connects like this.  The clump of hots is *always-hot* and you will not be using it.   The clump of all whites is kept together, and the neutral from the lamp is added to it.   The solitary is switched-hot for the lamp.

Comment: And she would need to pull the switch to figure out what goes back to the switch.

Comment: @EdBeal do you think the solitary hot is something other than the switched line?  It looks like it's never been inside a wirenut, possibly on a lug terminal.

Comment: I just want it to work and not burn down my house All of them were inside wire nuts

Comment: @Melissa That's what circuit breakers are for. There is a good chance that the lone blue wire is switched. What happened when you connected it to your fixture between white and blue? (That is, the fixture's black wire to the blue).

Comment: @EdBeal Removing the switch (or just its cover plate) might show the blue wire. My gut feeling is that is the case.

Comment: Thanks all. Connected black to blue and white to white. Installed a crossbar with grounding screw (whoever installed it before skipped it). Thanks again!